# Can't connect with Huginn login page

Tags: docker, github, web-scraping, rss

I already deployed Huginn on my linux server with Docker.

**Huginn on Github**: [link](https://github.com/huginn/huginn)

But when I ran `docker run -it -p 3000:3000 huginn/huginn`, and I wanted to connect Huginn login page with *Http://myserverIP:3000* on my browser, it doesn't respond.

[Browser response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JCncb.png)

How could I fix this problem? Or did I miss any details?

Answer (score 0):

Check the logs. Probably the database is not properly configured and foreman doesn't start creating the tables
You might need to alter the .env file and add the database related variables
(check google)